# Sass duplicate <styles> tag with the same content in the html file (Vue)

Tags: css

I have some sass files in my proyect to define generig sass variables and styles. To use this variables in components, I need configure sass loader in this way:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `
                    @import "@/styles/main.sass"
                `
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The main.sass file import all generic sass style sheets. This file contains:

```
// main.sass
@import "variables"
@import "typo"
```

With this I can use global sass variables in my vue components and It´s not necessary to import in each components.

Everything words fine but when I see the rendered html file of web app, the *style* tags are duplicated:

```
<style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap);</style>
<style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap);</style>
<style type="text/css">
#app {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
#app h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#app h1 > b {
  font-weight: 700;
}
#app strong > h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #4BA7EE;
}
#app {
  text-align: center;
}
#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap);</style>
<style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap);</style>
<style type="text/css">
#app[data-v-469af010] {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
#app h1[data-v-469af010] {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#app h1 > b[data-v-469af010] {
  font-weight: 700;
}
#app strong > h1[data-v-469af010] {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #4BA7EE;
}
h3[data-v-469af010] {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul[data-v-469af010] {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li[data-v-469af010] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a[data-v-469af010] {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

There is only one difference, the last *style* seems to be scoped

I don´t know if this is normal or the style sheets is being imported more than one time.

I have tried to comment the sass loader(vue.config.js) and every *style* tags disappear.

Comment: where did you look at this css file on Browser inspector devtools ?

Comment: I have this problem on massive APP and its causing performance issues. It seems the base styles, fonts & helper classes are being injected into each style block. Whereas we want he base styles once. And then each new style block should only contain scoped styles for that page or component. Did you solve this?